# Display label1 with the deviceid in VB

Tags: vb.net

What I'm trying to accomplish is to display `deviceId` when I plug it in to my computer.

Basically I would like `label1` to change to the deviceId.

I would like to accomplish this via VB but I haven't been able to find any samples to learn from can you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find the MSDN documentation to gather the information you want:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172516(v=vs.90).aspx

Once you have the information you just have to put it on your label.